# How to make ant4eclispe build a project with all its dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have several Eclipse projects that depend on each other (no cycles). Is it possible to use ant4eclipse to automatically resolve and build dependencies (preferrably to a single output folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We do it.

You will need to use Team Projects to tell ant4eclipse about which projects are available.